# Python append values to empty list by skipping values in between a list

Tags: python, arrays, for-loop, indexing, indices

Just a minimal example of what I want to achieve.

I have an array:

```
array = [1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10,1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10,....,1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10]
```

I would like to loop through this array and create a new array which looks like this:

```
new_array = [1,1,2,1,2,3,1,2,3,4,1,2,3,4,5,....,1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10]
```

i.e. loop through array `a`, get the first value (i.e. 1), **then skip the `remaining 9` values**, then get the first and the second value (i.e. 1,2), **then skip the `remaining 8` values**, and so on.

The idea I came up with was to create `indices` and use it in the following way:

```
In [1]: indices = np.arange(1,10,1)
Out[1]: array([1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9])

new_array = []
for i in array:
    for a,b in zip(indices,range(10)):
        new_array.append(i[0:a]) # here I am including i[0:1], i[0:2] and so on
```

So it loops through `array` and gets the first value, then skips the remaining 9 values, then gets the first two values and skips the remaining 8 values and so on.

But this doesn't seem to work. How can I achieve this ?

Comment: could you please come up with exact example

Comment: your question has ambiguity like what will happen when i reached to end of array in first or second part of skipping.

Comment: The above is the exact minimal example. I would like to get `new_array` from `array`. I believe I have explained the difference between `array` and `new_array`

Comment: @shivam: nanbaa, just skip pannanum nanbaa, first value, adhukku aprom first two,etc.. When the array ends, we stop.

Comment: You can easily do it with two for loops of range 10 when the inner takes all item with indices lower than the external. see my answer for more details.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For a signle list you can also use list extension for this:

```
list = [1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10]
output = []
i = 1
while i <= 10:
    output.extend(list[0:i])
    i +=1

print output
```

For your list you can extend this to:

```
list = [1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10]*10

output = []

i = 1
j = 0
k = 1
while k <= 10:
   output.extend(list[j:i])
   j +=10
   k +=1
   i = j+k

print output
```

Comment: Can you please explain step by step

Answer (score 2):

If you don't need all values (only pass your scheme)

```
list = [1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10] * 10
output = []

skip = 9
i = 0
while skip > 0:
    output.append(list[i])
    i += skip + 1
    skip -= 1
print(list)
print(output)
```

But your "new_array" doesn't pass your algorithm. Why not:

`[1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10,1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10,1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10]`
If I get first `1` (it has index `0`) after skip `9` values I will get `1`, after then skipping `8` values I won't get `2`

**Edit:** Ok, I understand now. This should work:

```
list = [1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10] * 10
output = []

skip = 9
i = 0
j = 0
add = 1
while skip >= 0:
    newList = list[i:j+1]
    for x in newList:
        output.append(x)
    i += skip + add
    j += skip + add + 1
    add += 1
    skip -= 1
print(output)
```

Comment: So... you can use two indexes - `i` and `j` and do this similarly.

Answer (score 1):

can you please try this code. I have tested this code on python 3 and it is working fine.

```
inp = [1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10] * 10
inp_len = len(inp);
output = [inp[0]]
skip = 9
limit= skip +2;
pointer = 1;
while skip > 0:
    pointer = pointer+skip;
    if(pointer >inp_len):
        pointer = pointer %inp_len;
    for x in inp[pointer : pointer+limit-skip ]:
        output.append(x);
    pointer= pointer+ limit-skip ;
    skip=skip-1;
print(inp)
print(output)
```

Explaination -  Adding default first element and then adding elements in below order.

- skip  9  elements = [1, 2]
- skip  8  elements = [1, 2, 3]
- skip  7  elements = [1, 2, 3, 4]
- skip  6  elements = [1, 2, 3, 4, 5]
- skip  5  elements = [1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6]
- skip  4  elements = [1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7]
- skip  3  elements = [1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8]
- skip  2  elements = [1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9]
- skip  1  elements = [1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10]

Please test it with your input . Here i am using a defined list.

Input list  -[1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10]

Output list  - [1, 1, 2, 1, 2, 3, 1, 2, 3, 4, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10]

Answer (score 0):

How about:

```
list = [1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10] * 10;
output = [];

take = 1;
index = 0;
while index < len(list):
    # take the "take" next elements, notice the "index" is not changing.
    for i in range(take):
        output.append(list[index + i]);
    # Skip the remaining values and increase the "take"
    index += 10;
    take += 1;
print(list)
print(output)
```

You can also go like this with two indices:

```
list = [1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10] * 10;
output = [];

index = 0;
for i in range(10):
    for j in range(10):
        if j <= i:
            output.append(list[index + i]);
        index++;
print(list)
print(output)
```

Answer (score 0):

it's not too different from printing a triangle with numbers from 1 to 10.

```
array     = [x for x in range(1,11)]*10 #here 10 means adding same list 10 times
new_array = []
for i in range(10):
    new_array += array[10*i:10*i+i+1]
print(new_array)
```

hope this helps!

It takes 0.0005 sec

Answer (score 0):

```
array = [1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10]*10
new_array = []

c=j=0
while c < len(array):
    for i in range(0,j):
        new_array.append(array[i])
        i+=1
    j+=1
    c+=10
print(new_array)
```

Output

```
[1, 1, 2, 1, 2, 3, 1, 2, 3, 4, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9]
```